# Holomorphic solutions of first order PDEs

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Consider a first order PDE of the following form: 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -\omega\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + f(x,t,u,u_x ),$$
$$u(x, 0) = u_0,$$
where $u(x,t): \mathbb{\mathbb{T}}\times[0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{C}^4$, $f$ is analytic, $u_0$ holomorphic on the strip $|\text{Im}(x)|<\sigma$, $\omega$ is a constant satisfying diophantine condtions:

there exist $\mu>0, \tau>1$ such that for any $m , n \in\mathbb{N}_+$, 
$$\left|\omega-\frac{m}{n}\right|>\mu|n|^{-\tau},$$
 Are there any global results for the existence of holomorphic solutions with respect to $x$ to this PDE?

(In the original post, I didn't specify the solutions are holomorphic with respect to $x$.)

Comment: For general $f$ I doubt it.  In the easy case that $u$ maps into $\mathbb C$, if $f(x,t,u,u_x)=u^2,u_0=a$, then the unique holomorphic solution is $u(t,x)=a/(1-at)$.  So for nonlinear equations, getting global results means restrictions on $f$ more than analyticity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example! I forgot to mention that I just need the solution to be holomorphic with respect to $x$. I am wondering whether there are global estimates about such non autonomous nonlinear first order PDEs.